# Submit user form only if it`s unique and have not been submitted before

Tags: forms, unique

I spent hours researching the best way to do this but so far have no answer. Hope someone can help.

Basically, here is the issue we are trying to solve: 
We need to collect information about our products in the company. To do this, we were planning to use some kind of forms (as an example - google forms). Idea is that one product can be submitted only once. How can I do it? Google forms only allow me to limit number of responses from one IP which is NOT what I need...

Comment: Do you have some unique identifier for each product? A SKU, UPC, etc.

Comment: Yes, each products has a unique SKU

Answer (score 0):

do you must use some third part service?

i think maybe you need code this logic by yourself. you can use the common way to solve the problem, for example, use the user_id & product_id.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Well, I do not code, and I know stackoverflkow is not a "write a code for me" service - I would be happy if someone can help, but for me it will take a year... That's why I am looking for third party service...